# Captcha validation in PHP HTML contact form

Tags: php, html

For a few days I am working on implementation of captcha into my contact form. I went through multiple tutorials and stackoverflow discussions, but it seems I am still doing something wrong (I am not yet very experienced with PHP so probably I miss something).

a) My contact form is working correctly (sending emails, checking for empty fields etc.)

b) Captcha is displaying correctly

c) Captcha verification does **not** work

For the contact form I use 3 files - .html file - containing the webpage and two .php files (captcha.php for creating the captcha, send-email.php for sending email and validations).

1) kontakt.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="de">
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div class="contact-form-container">
                            <form  class="contact-form" action="php/send-email.php"  method="post" novalidate>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="column width-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-fname form-element large" placeholder="Firma*" tabindex="1" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="column width-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-lname form-element large" placeholder="Ihr Name*" tabindex="2" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column width-6">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-email form-element large" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse*" tabindex="3" required>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="column width-6">
                                        <input type="tel" name="telefonnummer" class="form-website form-element large" placeholder="Telefonnummer*" tabindex="4" required>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="column width-12">
                                        <div class="field-wrapper">
                                            <textarea name="message" class="form-message form-element large" placeholder="Nachricht*" tabindex="7" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="column width-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="honeypot" class="form-honeypot form-element large">
                                    </div>           
                                       <div class="elem-group column width-12">
                                           <label for="captcha">Captcha</label>
                                           <img src="php/captcha.php" alt="CAPTCHA" class="captcha-image"><i class="form fas fa-redo refresh-captcha"></i>
                                           <br><br>
                                           <input class="form-message form-element" type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha_challenge" pattern="[A-Z]{6}">                   
                                       </div>
                                    <div class="column width-12">                                           
                                           <input  type="submit" value="Senden" class="form-submit button medium bkg-theme bkg-hover-theme color-white color-hover-white">
                                    </div>              
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="form-response center"></div>           
                        </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

2) captcha.php (to generate captcha image, as far as I am aware it works properly)

```
<?php

session_start();

$permitted_chars = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';

function generate_string($input, $strength = 10) {
    $input_length = strlen($input);
    $random_string = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $strength; $i++) {
        $random_character = $input[mt_rand(0, $input_length - 1)];
        $random_string .= $random_character;
    }

    return $random_string;
}

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);

imageantialias($image, true);

$colors = [];

$red = rand(125, 175);
$green = rand(125, 175);
$blue = rand(125, 175);

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  $colors[] = imagecolorallocate($image, $red - 20*$i, $green - 20*$i, $blue - 20*$i);
}

imagefill($image, 0, 0, $colors[0]);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  imagesetthickness($image, rand(2, 10));
  $line_color = $colors[rand(1, 4)];
  imagerectangle($image, rand(-10, 190), rand(-10, 10), rand(-10, 190), rand(40, 60), $line_color);
}

$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolors = [$black, $white];

$font = 'arial.ttf';

$string_length = 6;
$captcha_string = generate_string($permitted_chars, $string_length);

$_SESSION['captcha_text'] = $captcha_string;

for($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++) {
  $letter_space = 170/$string_length;
  $initial = 15;

  imagettftext($image, 24, rand(-15, 15), $initial + $i*$letter_space, rand(25, 45), $textcolors[rand(0, 1)], $font, $captcha_string[$i]);
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

3) send-email.php (to send email and do verification)

```
<?php
// Your Email
    $recipient = "mymail"; 


    // Check $recipient
    if($recipient === '') {
        returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
            constructAjaxResponseArray(
                FALSE,
                'RECIPIENT_IS_NOT_SET',
                array('error_message'=> 'RECIPIENT email address is not set. Please configure the script.')
            )
        );
    }

if ($_POST['captcha_challenge'] == $_SESSION['captcha_text']) {


    // Check for empty required field
    if(!isset($_POST["email"]) || !isset($_POST["fname"]) || !isset($_POST["message"])) {
        returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
            constructAjaxResponseArray(
                FALSE,
                'MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS',
                array('error_message'=> 'MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS should not be occurred.')
            )
        );
    }

    // Sanitize input
    $fname  = filter_var($_POST["fname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lname  = filter_var($_POST["lname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);


    // Headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$fname.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    // Subject
    $subject = "Neue E-Mail von Kontakt Formular";

    // Build Message
    $email_content = "Firma: $fname\n";
    $email_content .= "Ihr Name: $lname\n";
    $email_content .= "Telefon nummer: $telefonnummer\n"; 
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Nachricht:\n$message\n\n\n";
    $email_content .= "CLIENT IP:\n".get_client_ip()."\n";
    $email_content .= "HOST IP:\n".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']."\n";

else {
    } echo '<p>Captcha verification is wrong. Take other action.</p>';

}


// Check if sent
try {
    $sendmailResult = mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $headers);
    if( $sendmailResult === TRUE ) {
        returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
            constructAjaxResponseArray(
                TRUE
            )
        );
    } else {
        returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
            constructAjaxResponseArray(
                FALSE,
                'ERROR_AT_PHPMAIL',
                array('error_information'=> error_get_last() )
            )
        );
    }
} catch (Exception $_e) {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            TRUE,
            'ERROR_AT_PHPMAIL',
            array('error_message'=> $_e->getMessage())
        )
    );
}


function constructAjaxResponseArray ($_response, $_message = '', $_json = null) {
    $_responseArray = array();
    $_response = ( $_response === TRUE ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $_responseArray['response'] = $_response;
    if(isset($_message)) $_responseArray['message'] = $_message;
    if(isset($_json)) $_responseArray['json'] = $_json;

    return $_responseArray;
}

function returnAndExitAjaxResponse ($_ajaxResponse) {
    if(!$_ajaxResponse){
        $_ajaxResponse = array('response'=>false,'message'=>'Unknown error occurred.');
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($_ajaxResponse);
    die();
}


// Function to get the client IP address
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    } else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    } else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    } else {
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    }
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

Now, if I leave the captcha field empty, then email is sent to mail email address from contact form. However, if I input anything into captcha_challenge field (doesn't matter if it's correct or not) then contact form freezes after submitting and does not send an email.

I think the reason of errors this part of send-email.php code (neverthelesss, I've got no idea how to fix it):

```
if ($_POST['captcha_challenge'] == $_SESSION['captcha_text']) { 
//code 
else {
        } echo '<p>Captcha verification is wrong. Take other action.</p>';

    }
```

I tried many different options to verify this captcha or use many other captcha ideas. Now I am pretty clueless as its another day of failed tests with my limited php knowledge.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use Google's reCaptcha?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST['captcha_challenge']);` and `var_dump($_SESSION['captcha_text']);` right before you compare them to see what they contain.

Comment: You have syntax error on `send-email.php` file

Comment: @MilanG not helpful. Aside from the fact that it can take an annoyingly long time to do recaptcha (10-20 seconds of clicking sometimes), not everyone wants to use 3rd party solutions or force their customers to train Google's machine learning algos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `session_start();` on send-email.php

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I missed it. It almost works now - if user puts the correct captcha then the email is sent. 
However, if captcha is incorrect then it freezes after submitting, I have changed 'else {
         echo '<p>Captcha verification is wrong. Take other action.</p>';

    }' 
into
else {
        die(Captcha verification is wrong. Take other action.)';

    }

but still doesn't cancels itself after wrong captcha provided.

Comment: I do it the other way. if $captcha != $userCaptcha then cancel the execution and return an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pasting the captcha.php here

```
 <?php
$post = [
   'secret' => '6LfcOEcUAAAAABldSkevRJL75VSrvheVbc_4z9wU', //Enter the secret key provided by the google (just copy and paste it)
   'response' => $_POST['googleResponse'],

];
$ch = curl_init();
echo 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_export ($response);
// echo $response;
?>
```

captcha.js here

```
////////   GOOGLE RECAPTCHA CLIENT SIDE AND SERVER SIDE VERIFICATION   /////////////

            //----------------------------------------------------/
           // onloadCallback()
          // this 
         //----------------------------------------------------/




 var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {    // oncallback render a div with id html_element
          'sitekey' : '6LfcOEcUAAAAAAia1cMp60bnm1PMaFrmJ808il_D', // sitekey for the  captcha 
          'theme' : 'light',           // change the theme for light and dark
          'widgetId': 'widgetId',      // add widget id attribute which is optional
          callback(){
            console.log( 'another callback function here');

             response = grecaptcha.getResponse();    // get the value of response when user submits recaptcha
            console.log('response from google : ', response);

            // send post method to captcha php that is usin curl post request for cross domain
             $.post("captcha.php",
                    {
                      googleResponse: response     // pass the google response

                    },
                      function(response, status){   // pass two parameters respnse  and status 
                           console.log("response after ssv : ", response, status); 

                           if ( status == 'success'){
                             captchaSuccess = status;
                             captchares = captchaSuccess;
                            console.log("captchaSuccess :", captchaSuccess);


                           }
                           // alert response and the status here after verification from google 
                      });
            }
        });
    };
```

and here is my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>captcha</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
<div id="html_element"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
<script src="captcha.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

use this snippet to include captchav2 validation. you just have to include this in your code and you're ready to go, it only contains code related to captchav2, there is nothing extra. I hope it will help you.